# Animating views in a linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am using a LinearLayout with an edittext and then an image. On a button click I animate my image out of the screen thus giving space to the edittext. But the edittext resizes its width suddenly without animating.
How can I achieve this that the edittext resizes with animation. Pls help
Thanks in advance!!!!

Edit1: My xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/search_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hj_back_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_arrow_back_grey" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/hj_search_edittext"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/hj_search_text"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/hj_margin_small"
    android:textColor="@color/hj_search_text_color"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hj_search_bar_border_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/hj_font_small" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_cart_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_shopping_cart_grey" />
```

In the above xml my_cart_icon moves to the right. I want my edittext to scale it smoothly to fill the left space.

Comment: can you provide your xml layout file? and what you animating either EditText or ImageView?

Comment: @ Apar Amin I have updated my question

Comment: have you try it with RelativeLayout?, and regarding your problem then its happened because you assign wrap_content, if you don't have any other view in row then you can give weight to ImageView(my_cart_icon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve a simple animation effect of hiding/removing one of the views and stretching the others using [`android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:animateLayoutChanges). Hope it helps!

Comment: One small thing...as the image animates in the edittext resizes but why is it happeing that its showing a white layer above the image. but as soon as I click on any thing in the actionbar that blur goes away and the image is clearly visible